# Logging into 'Test Servers' failed

Tags: telegram, telethon, testserver

I've tried to login to **Telegram Test Servers** according to the library's documentation , to avoid polluting my original account while testing my code, using the Telethon.
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/developing/test-servers.html#test-servers

It keeps returning the

> **'Invalid Code. Please try again.'**

after that I tried to Signup for the Account by **Telegram Official Desktop App** ***(Add Another Account - Test Server)*** but now it says

> **'You have deleted your account too many times try again in a few days'**

**I didn't delete/recreate my Account at all though!**

Any idea what's going on? how should I signup and login to a Test Server account and use it as my client account properly?

Stay Safe V

Comment: Looks like it has to be six digits now, not five ([reference](https://t.me/gramme_rs/9741)).